# Prove $\frac{a^2b^2}{(a-c)(b-c)}+ \frac{b^2c^2}{(b-a)(c-a)} + \frac{c^2a^2}{(c-b)(a-b)} = ab+bc+ca$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Prove $$\frac{a^2b^2}{(a-c)(b-c)}+ \frac{b^2c^2}{(b-a)(c-a)} + \frac{c^2a^2}{(c-b)(a-b)} = ab+bc+ca$$

Can you help me to prove this equality? When I multiple left side, I get more complicated expression. Obviously I need to add something like shift for our variables or something else. I would be grateful for help.

Comment: For $a=b=c$ the RHS is $3a^2$ and the LHS is $\infty$.

Comment: The Statement is true, we must assume that $$a\ne c,b\ne c,a\ne b$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiply the whole thing by the product of the denominators.

Comment: I solved this. Thank you a lot people.

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

If we clear the denominators we get $$ a^2b^2(a-b) + b^2c^2(b-c)+c^2a^2(c-a)=(ab+bc+ca)(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)$$

which are polynomials of degree 3 (say on $a$) on both sides. So the identity is true if it is true of 4 different values of $a$